# adding text on buttons angular x-editable

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

Hi I need to add "save" and "cancel" text on the editable form buttons. There are two ways 
1)By using "default" theme

```
 mainApp.run(function(editableOptions){      
       editableOptions.theme = 'default'; 
});
```

2) To do it the way it is done in this example
   http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/7474/

Is there any way that I can use the "bs3" theme and globally configure to have save and cancel text while editing the form

```
mainApp.run(function(editableOptions){   
           editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually override the button template like this

```
app.run(function(editableOptions,editableThemes) {
      editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
      editableThemes['bs3'].submitTpl = '<button type="submit">ok</button>';
});
```

I also created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stealop/NfPcH/10728/)